# equalTo returning null from Firebase?

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, react-native

In my React Native App, I currently am trying to pull all items that have the `selected` property set to "true" from the database. However, when I log the results of this query, they are all being returned as `null` (even though expected response should be returning two objects). My relevant code as well as Firebase structure are included below, please let me know if you spot anything.

```
const rootRef = new Firebase(`${ config.FIREBASE_ROOT }`)

var queryRef = rootRef.orderByChild("items/selected");

var solution = queryRef.equalTo("true").once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(snap.val())
 });
```

Firebase JSON:

```
"items": 
[
    {
    "title":"ball",
    "selected": "false"
    },

    {
    "title":"dog",
    "selected": "true"
    },

    {
    "title":"phone",
    "selected": "false"
    },

    {
    "title":"cup",
    "selected": "true"
    }
],
```

Comment: Answer below. But I also noticed that you're storing the items as an array in the JSON tree, which is often leads to problems. Be sure to read the relevant [section in the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks--but I thought in JSON if you have several objects of the same type they should be stored as an array? In this case each of my items has the same attributes (same type of object) so I thought I needed to store them in an array. How else should I go about doing this?

Comment: Read the (Firebase documentation on storing lists of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push). In fact, I highly recommend that you read that guide entirely. A few hours spent there, will save much more time down the line.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen great, thanks for pointing me to this documentation. It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

When you run an Firebase query on a location, it takes each child node under that location and then evaluates the condition you specify. If you take each child under `items`, you'll see there is no path `items/selected` under there.

You query is instead:

```
var itemsRef = rootRef.child("items");
var queryRef = itemsRef.orderByChild("selected");
```

Comment: Just made the modifications (and also changed my JSON to remove arrays) and this still seems to return null values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
where("selected" = true)
```

instead of equalTo()